# How to accsss R data frame contents using element in factor level

Tags: r, dataframe

As below, dataframe *factorizedss* is the factorized version of a sourcedata dataframe ss.

```
ss <- data.frame(c('a','b','a'), c(1,2,1));  #There are string columns and number columns. 
                                             #So, I factorized them as below.

factorizedss <- data.frame(lapply(ss, as.factor)); #factorized version
indices <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,2), c(1,1,1,2));     #Now, given integer indices
```

With given *indices*, using *factorizedss*, is it possible to get corresponding element of the source dataframe as below? (The purpose is to access data frame element by integer number in factor level )

> a 1
>
> a 1
>
> b 1
>
> b 2

Comment: Could you explain your expected output? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: perhaps something like `mapply("[", factorizedss, indices)`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first column like this

```
factorizedss[indices[,1],][,1]
```

and the second in a similar way

```
factorizedss[indices[,2],][,2]
```

It gets more difficult when trying to combine them, you might have to convert them back to native types

```
 t(rbind(as.character(factorizedss[indices[,1],][,1]),as.numeric(factorizedss[indices[,2],][,2])))
```